# Sleep statement between go statements

Tags: go, goroutine

I saw the below setup in a code base today. Does the Sleep() function have any effect? I suppose it's there to guarantee that serverA is running before serverB starts, but since execution of both may be deferred until later, this is not really guaranteed, right?

```
func main() {

    go util.Execute("run", serverA)

    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)

    go util.Execute("run", serverB)

    for {
        log.Println("running")
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 30)
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to ask the original author their true intent with this code, but more than likely you're right. It does look like a misguided attempt at synchronization (as you suggest, trying to ensure one server starts before the other). If that is the intent, this is absolutely the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: I would think your suspicions were correct, but I'm not sure this question is really answerable unless the original author is on SO and can explain their thinking.

Comment: FWIW, the correct way to do what it looks like they're trying to do would be to have the first server use either a channel or a `sync.Cond` to notify `main` when it is "safe" to start the second server.

Comment: @Adrian This is unfortunately not possible, since the original author is not reachable anymore. The program as it is written should have a well specified (though non-deterministic) behavior, regardless of the behavior of the utility Execute function, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "well-specified" here... You're right that it's non-deterministic, but the behavior of `Execute` is certainly relevant. The most specific you can be about this behavior is "it waits 500ms between the two calls to `Execute`."

Comment: Also bear in mind that with a static 500ms delay, there are environmental factors that can have a significant impact on the resulting behavior. On a performant system with nothing else running, 500ms might be plenty of time for operations to complete which might take much longer on a system with less performance and/or other processes consuming CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have an effect that it will wait 500 ms before the next goroutine will attempt to run and start serverB. And you're correct that it's not really guaranteed that serverA will completely start within that time.

A better strategy would be to check for some kind of signal from serverA that it is fully running, but not knowing anything about what type of server that is it would be hard to advise.

Comment: As I understand, it may also happen that serverB is started before serverA, so serverA hasn't even begun to start after the Sleep() wait is over. Is this correct?

Comment: That is absolutely possible, if somewhat unlikely. But that possibility is why a signal is a better solution than an arbitrary sleep.